# broadcasting user's with socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

well a want to make a simple chat system, and for that i have to show
all clients witch are connected.i try sivrel techniques and it dons't work.
i tried to emit a socket when a client connect and it dons't work.
that's what i tried:

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
 let user = req.body.username
 let pass = req.body.password
 console.log("le user est = " + user + " \nle password est = " + pass);
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [user,pass], function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results.length);
  console.log(results[0]);      
  if (results.length==1){
   const user_id =  results[0]
   io.sockets.emit('new_user',{user:results[1]})
   req.login(user_id,(err)=>{
    res.redirect('/home');
   })
  }else {
   res.redirect('/');
  }
 });
});
```

and that the full code :
server.js:

```js
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let bodyParser = require('body-parser')
let server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
let session = require('express-session')
let MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
let passport = require('passport');
let mysql = require('mysql');
let hbs = require('hbs')
var options = {
 host: 'localhost',
 user: 'root',
 password: '',
 database: 'robot'
};
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);
let connection = mysql.createConnection(options); 
connection.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) {
  console.error('MYSQL error connecting : ' + err.stack);
  return;
 } 
 console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
app.use(session({
 secret: 'ldifgquoqjfejg',
 store: sessionStore,
   //comme elle change que lorsque on modéfie la session
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
  //cookie: { secure: true }
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//hbs configure
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
hbs.localsAsTemplateData(app);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
 res.render('login');
});
app.get('/home', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('index');
});
app.get('/robot', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('robot');
});
app.get('/userlist', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('listeuser'); 
});
app.get('/history', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('history'); 
});
app.get('/chat', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('chat'); 
});
app.get('/cam', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('cam'); 
});
app.get('/bras', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('bras'); 
});
app.get('/base', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('base'); 
});
app.get('/ajout', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res)=>{
 app.locals.user = req.user.username
 res.render('ajout'); 
});
app.get('/Logout', (req, res)=>{
 req.logout();
 req.session.destroy();
 res.redirect('/');
});

app.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
 let user = req.body.username
 let pass = req.body.password
 console.log("le user est = " + user + " \nle password est = " + pass);
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [user,pass], function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results.length);
  console.log(results[0]);      
  if (results.length==1){
   const user_id =  results[0]
   io.sockets.emit('new_user',{user:results[1]})
   req.login(user_id,(err)=>{
    res.redirect('/home');
   })
  }else {
   res.redirect('/');
  }
 });
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
 done(null, user_id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
 done(null, user_id);
});
//socket
 io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
  socket.emit('user','data')
 });
 
//socket
server.listen(8000);
app.use(express.static('./views'));
function authenticationMiddleware(){
 return(req, res, next)=>{
  //console.log('req.session.passport.user: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.passport)}')
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
  res.redirect('/')
 }
}
```

and the chat.html

```js
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000')
                    socket.on('new_user',(data)=>{
                        document.getElementById('ilyes').innerHTML=data.user
                    })
                </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? any error? something? Also your example is far from minimal, could you try to reduce it to your actual problem?

Comment: the actual problem is in the first code.

Comment: when a user connect a want to send a socket to tell athoer user's that's he is connected, but it dons't work a don't know why

Comment: I don't know either, sorry, can't run your code and you gave me no clue about what's going on here. Can't spend that much time trying to figure out with only reading. All i can advise you is do more debugging, log your values, check if they're right and such..